# C# LINQ query to return matching characters or whole words like Google Search

Tags: c#, linq, search, textbox

I have an entity database (EmployeeDB) that contains names in a column call "Names".
The name can be "Jim A McCloud, JJ Bob, Bing Bing Bop, John Doe, Woody Be Bad McCloud, etc..".

I have a text box that the user can type a text and it will return the results matching either the character that they type or the substring they type (whole or partial words) similar to Google Search. The result is then grab from the database and display in a Div area underneath the text box where they can pick which matching results to use.

Right now, I only can return words matching the first character type. Is there a LINQ query I can use to continuously match whole words or partial words similar to Google Search? Like for example, using the db data above, if I type "J" the result will return Jim A McCloud, JJ Bob as a selectable option. Then if I type "JJ B" the result will return only JJ Bob, but continuously updating the search list with every key press.

Thanks,

-B

Comment: You should include relevant excerpts of the code you have working already

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna need either a webservice or a WebMethod.

[here's a pretty basic example of what you need to get this to work](http://jquery-with-asp.net/2011/07/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-asp-net/)

linq query would look something like this:

```
var retVal = listOfNames.Where(x => x.Contains(yourInputString)).ToList();
```